# Spring-XD Job Mail Notification

Tags: rest, email, notifications, spring-batch, spring-xd

We are running few jobs every day using Spring-XD and it might happen the jobs might fail. Spring-XD has dashboard which shows the details of the jobs and even there are REST api's which could be used to fetch the details of the jobs.

We are planning to automate this process by sending out mail notification when there is job failure or sending out of one mail that contains the status of all the jobs.

There are couple of approaches which we can use

1. Use the REST api's (/jobs/executions?jobname=xx), transform json to html and use the mail sink to send out the mails to the required recipients
2. Get the status from the Spring-Metadata repository database and use mail-api to send out the mails. This would be like having separate module
3. We can use the Management over JMX but not sure how to send out mails.

Need your suggestions in arriving on best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an XD stream that [listens for job events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_retrieve_job_notifications), filters success/failure and send failures to the [mail sink](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#mail)